# How can I add exisiting Keycloack instance as IDP to Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I have a running Keycloack instance with users in it. Recently the company has decided to migrate from Keycloack to Azure B2C, but we still need to allow users to login through Keycloack for a while. Is it possible to configure our current Keycloack instance as IDP for Azure B2C tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as Keycloak supports OAuth 1.0, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, or SAML [protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).